# Renderizar um layout em vários sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Tenho a seguinte situação, tenho vários sites com layouts e banco de dados diferentes, mas eu queria que eles usassem a mesma área administrativa, as mesmas gems, pois se eu precisar arrumar um bug na área administrativa ou atualizar uma gem eu atualizaria em um lugar e ele automaticamente valeria para as outros sites, como eu poderia construir isso.

Comment: Crie uma aplicação separada para a área administrativa.

Answer (score 2):

Amigo, acredito que você tenha que usar engines: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html

Que são uma especie de plugin, só que mais poderoso. Você pode criar controladores e telas na engine e então importar na sua aplicacao como um plugin.

Aparentemente, o Devise funciona na forma de uma engine.